# Why is Angular proxy server copying the origin url to the request url?

Tags: angular, api, proxy

My angular project is running at http://127.0.0.1:4200 From http://127.0.0.1:4200/login I make a request to the api running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register but I receive error 404 because of the wrong url requested: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/127.0.0.1:8000/api/register". So Angular proxy sends the request to http://127.0.0.1:4200/127.0.0.1:8000/api/register instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register.

proxy.conf.json is configured as fallows:

```
{
    "/api/register/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    API_BASE_PATH: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
};
```

and environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    API_BASE_PATH: '127.0.0.1:8000/api'
};
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the service file or the other file from where you are making HTTP get or post request to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using `proxy.conf.json` for development purpose

you have to change it like this

```
{
"/register/*": {
"target": "http://localhost:8000/api",
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true
}
}
```

and change

**environment.ts:**

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
API_BASE_PATH: ''
};
```

proxy config do the rest

Comment: One mor question, on the server where I use a real proxy nginx I have to change the API_BASE_PATH: ' to the real base path on the server, like http://localhost:8000/api? and delete the proxy.conf.json file or at least deactivate it ?

Comment: yes, in server `proxy config` will not work, `proxy config` is developer hack, it only use in development mode, server deployment no need to worry about `proxy.config`

Comment: Cheers ..!! ,have a nice day !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202323/discussion-between-chathuran-and-user11903678).